# Firebase Cloud Functions with Typescript, how to cast a complex interface

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the app side I am able to query a collection and auto-cast the result as a interface. Positions has a constructer that takes in interface IPosition.

It seems doing the same on cloud functions side doesn't allow the functions to deploy. Its hard to debug the code since it has to be deployed and only works when the code works (local serve requires some permissions).

I was able to narrow it down by removing most of my code and re-adding it line by line until I stumbled on this.

I'm guessing this has to do with the interface having properties that are of type `enum`. Casting `position` as IPosition doesn't work either.

Also the interface is imported from another module (parent app module)

```
import { Position } from '../../src/app/models/position';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { UserRecord } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth';

admin.initializeApp();
const promisePool = require('es6-promise-pool');
const PromisePool = promisePool.PromisePool;
// const secureCompare = require('secure-compare');
const MAX_CONCURRENT = 3;

const store = admin.firestore();

exports.updateMetrics = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // const key = req.query.key;

  // // Exit if the keys don't match.
  // if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
  //   console.log(
  //     'The key provided in the request does not match the key set in the environment. Check that',
  //     key,
  //     'matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`'
  //   );
  //   res
  //     .status(403)
  //     .send(
  //       'Security key does not match. Make sure your "key" URL query parameter matches the ' +
  //         'cron.key environment variable.'
  //     );
  //   return null;
  // }

  // Fetch all user.
  return getUsers()
    .then(users => {
      // Use a pool so that we delete maximum `MAX_CONCURRENT` users in parallel.
      const pool = new PromisePool(
        () => runMetricsAnalysis(users),
        MAX_CONCURRENT
      );
      return pool.start();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('metrics updated');
      res.send('metrics updated');
      return null;
    });
});

/**
 * Returns the list of all users.
 */
function getUsers(users: UserRecord[] = [], nextPageToken?: string) {
  let tempUsers: UserRecord[] = users;
  return admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(result => {
      // Concat with list of previously found users if there was more than 1000 users.
      tempUsers = tempUsers.concat(result.users);

      // If there are more users to fetch we fetch them.
      if (result.pageToken) {
        return getUsers(tempUsers, result.pageToken);
      }

      return tempUsers;
    });
}

function runMetricsAnalysis(users: UserRecord[]) {
  if (users.length > 0) {
    const user = users.pop();
    if (user != null) {
      return getPositions(user)
        .then(positions => {
          const metrics = generateMetrics(positions);
          console.log('metrics', metrics);
          return null;
          // return writeMetrics(user.uid, metrics).catch(function(err) {
          //   console.error(err);
          //   return null;
          // });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.error(err);
          return null;
        });
    }
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}

/**
 * Returns the list of positions for the previous month.
 */
function getPositions(user: UserRecord) {
  return store
    .collection(`users/${user.uid}/positions`)
    .orderBy('postedDate', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
}

interface IMetrics {
  portfolioValue: number;
  profitLoss: number;
  fees: number;
}

/**
 * Generate metrics from positions
 */
function generateMetrics(positions: Array<any>): IMetrics {
  let portfolioValue = 0;
  let profitLoss = 0;
  let fees = 0;
  if (positions.length > 0) {
    console.log('positions 5', positions);
    positions
      .map(position => new Position(position))
      .map(position => {
        portfolioValue += position.positionValue;
        profitLoss += position.profitLossClosedQuantity;
        fees += position.fees;
      });
  }

  const IMetric = {
    portfolioValue: portfolioValue,
    profitLoss: profitLoss,
    fees: fees
  };
  return IMetric;
}
```

**Position**

```
export interface IPosition {
  ...
}

export class Position implements IPosition {
  ...

  constructor(position: IPosition) {
  ...
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I was unable to see an error previously for some reason (probably because it just deployed a cached version of the function that works.

```
Here is the error: 

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/AceGreen/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Dev/Web/TradingTracker/functions/lib/src/app/models/position.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/AceGreen/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Dev/Web/TradingTracker/functions/lib/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
```

**position.js translation**

```
const app_1 = require("firebase/app");
var Timestamp = app_1.firestore.Timestamp;
```

Comment: I'm confused.  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What's the problem?  You're showing log output, but not the line of code that generates it.  You're showing functions, but not how they're being called.

Comment: I added the console log to show the output. All I do is call getPositionsForPreviousMonth and then pass its value to generateMetrics. console log shows that this works. Except that map to Position doesn't go through. And by that I mean, the whole function doesn't get deployed and its making it hard to debug

Comment: I'm still confused.  What do you mean by "map to Postition doesn't go through"?  Is there an error message?  What line generates the error?  What exactly is `Position` anyway?  If it's an interface, you can't simply `new` it up.

Comment: Its a cloud function so no error messages on lint, but the functions don't get deployed. I can only see the console.logs on firebase web interface ONLY when the functions have no "errors". Position is a class that has a constructor that takes IPosition (see description)

Comment: You going to have to give more information.  "no errors" and "functions don't get deployed" aren't clear enough.  You should show all relevant code here, especially Position and IPosition.

Comment: Have you even defined a Cloud Function trigger?  If you haven't defined a trigger, nothing will happen during deployment.

Comment: Added al the code, the trigger is an http trigger. Just to clarify, the function deploys when I comment the map of Position out, and I just console.log the position

Comment: I still don't know what you mean when you're saying that the function doesn't deploy.  Is there an error shown by the CLI at the time of deployment?  I find it really hard to believe that the deployment of anything would fail without at least an error message.

Comment: No nothing on Lint. There is no syntax issues or such. Just this map doesn't seem to be accepted and it doesn't actually deploy, it just uses the last "correct" version of that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. There issue seems to have been how I imported Timestamp.

```
const app_1 = require("firebase/app");
var Timestamp = app_1.firestore.Timestamp;
```

Correct way:

```
const app_1 = require("firebase");
var Timestamp = app_1.firestore.Timestamp;
```

**IMPORTANT Note:**

- It seems firebase deploy --only functions will use a cached version of your function if it can't resolve the current function. I say this because running `lint` when I had a reference to Timestamp in my function resulted in no error and it looked like the deployment was successful. Since I had the same function already deployed, it seems to have used a cached version.
- I was only able to catch the issue when I switched computers and had to reinstall the firebase-cli and redeploy, then it pointed out the incorrect reference to Timestamp.